# Use env with environment variables from file

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

Let's say I have a file (called `e`) with this content:

```
a=3
b="5 6"
```

How can I get each one to be interpreted as a separate argument to `env`? That is, to have it equivalent to:

```
$ env a=3 b="5 6" ruby -e 'p ENV["a"]; p ENV["b"]'
"3"
"5 6"
$ env a=3 "b=5 6" ruby -e 'p ENV["a"]; p ENV["b"]'
"3"
"5 6"
```

This one obviously doesn't work because of the space:

```
env $(cat e) ruby -e 'p ENV["a"]; p ENV["b"]'
```

But neither does this one:

```
IFS=$'\n' env $(cat e) ruby -e 'p ENV["a"]; p ENV["b"]'
```

And quoting `$(cat e)` will result in:

```
"1\nb=2 3"
nil
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19331497/set-environment-variables-from-file may assist you.

Comment: @Flup Thanks, but I don't want to export the variables to the shell and have them linger there.

Comment: See the second (and much more upvoted) answer that uses `env` to keep the variables local.

Comment: @Flup No luck: https://gist.github.com/cataphract/316698c7843a21815cbe16096318aeb9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of not using the right tool for the job.  `env` isn't the only tool that sets environment variables and then chain loads another program.  And it doesn't read variable data from file.

Of course, the `.` a.k.a. `source` command is not the right tool for this job, either.

1. It permits the file to unexpectedly contain shell commands *other than* simple variable assignments, which in certain circumstances (depending from what the configuration file is) can be a massive security hole.
2. A series of assignments as in the example in the question, sourced by `.`, sets *shell* variables, not *environment* variables.  They aren't automatically exported.

The right tools are ordinary chain-loading tools from several toolsets of such tools.

One such is `read-conf` from [the nosh toolset](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/Softwares/nosh/), designed to read exactly this kind of configuration file (such as [`/etc/rc.conf` from — say — PC-BSD](https://github.com/pcbsd/pcbsd/blob/master/overlays/install-overlay/etc/rc.conf)) and set environment variables *without* implementing and opening up configuration *data* files to an entire shell language syntax:

```
jdebp % uname
Linux
jdebp % cat e
a=3
b="5 6"
jdebp % read-conf e printenv | tail -n 3
USER=jdebp
a=3
b=5 6
jdebp %
```

```
jdebp % uname
FreeBSD
jdebp % read-conf /etc/rc.conf printenv | head -n 2
cron_enable=NO
sendmail_msp_queue_enable=NO
jdebp %
```

Another such tool is Wayne Marshall's [`runenv`](http://b0llix.net/perp/site.cgi?page=runenv.8) from perp.

Comment: Thanks. But I wonder why it's so difficult to take a file and have each line of it be an argument in bash.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need `env` here. In any Bourne-like shell (assuming the file is in `sh` syntax like in your example):

```
(set -a; . ./e && ruby -e 'p ENV["a"]; p ENV["b"]')
```

(`set -a` causes all future variable assignments to be exported to the environment).

You could also do:

```
cat e - << 'EOF' | paste -sd ' ' - | sh
ruby -e 'p ENV["a"]; p ENV["b"]'
EOF
```

That is join all the lines in the `e` file and that ruby command line to build a long command line for `sh` to interpret (still assuming that `e` file is in `sh` syntax as those double quotes suggest). That assumes the assignments are single line.